# Communicate Between two Matlab Sessions Using Data Transfer Cable

Tags: matlab, usb, data-transfer

We have a shared PC in our LAB, connected to a Vector Network Analyzer (VNA). The PC communicates with the VNA through GPIB port, using Matlab functions. For my work, i need to acquire real-time data from the VNA into my own PC, which is few meters away from the VNA PC. I dont want to have wireless solutions due to the interference that might happen. I intend to buy a USB data transfer cable to connect the Matlab. But i couldn't find in google any similar idea to do so. I was wondering is such a solution practical? Does anybody has the same experience? And will be any problem regarding the drivers?

Answer (score 0):

in USB bus systems there can only be **one** *USB host* all other devices are in *USB device mode*.in most cases the USB controllers of PCs are not capable of *USB device mode*, they all want to be USB host. in other bus systems like I2C this is called *master-slave architecture*

if you are lucky one of your PCs can be set to *device mode* and in this case this will work but your chances are very slim (because of the problem with the USB host and USB device mode)

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/195765/is-usb-to-usb-data-transfer-between-two-linux-oses-possible

a better solution would be to use **ethernet**

there are also modules in MATLAB for *real-time communication over ethernet* (Real-Time Transmit and Receive over Ethernet)

if your pcs have unused ethernet ports use an *ethernet crossover cable* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable) and connect the pcs (i.e. http://www.ccm.net/faq/6340-connect-pcs-using-a-crossover-ethernet-cable)

else use an *ethernet switch* (or *hub*) to establish the ethernet communication between the pcs

beside MATLAB for communication you can use i.e. `ssh` or install a *vnc server* on one of the machines and remote-control it with a *vnc client* on the other,...

**USB**

with *USB-to-ethernet adapters* (ebay,...) you can use *ethernet over usb* when connecting the usb-to-ethernet adapters via a ethernet crossover cable

another possibility is to use two *USB-to-serial adapters* and connect them with a *RS-232 crossover cable* and then use RS-232 protocol for communication (putty,...)

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i intend to buy something like this : https://www.amazon.de/Datenkabel-High-Speed-Linkkabel-einfachster-Datenaustausch/dp/B00A0I1ZWO/ref=s9_simh_gw_g147_i1_r?pf_rd_m=A3JWKAKR8XB7XF&pf_rd_s=&pf_rd_r=SE3Q8AYHXN1XYH9B34TX&pf_rd_t=36701&pf_rd_p=e23226ec-1f60-41f4-9435-2294c6d8b519&pf_rd_i=desktop. Hopefully, thanks to the the circuit in the middle of the cable, i should be able to communicate between  two Matlabs using Instrument Control Toolbox. Do you think the chance is still slim?

Comment: No, if there is a circuit then it will work for sure on windows,  on linux maybe there are minor problems...

Answer (score 0):

For such connection i.e. a long distance and fast and less expensive its best to use LAN cable which is easy  for PC and VNA. I would suggest u try the same